# JSONArray not created while running android code

Tags: android, json

I am parsing a response string received from a  url in JSON format. The code stops at the line for creating JSONArray. It does not print any log or exception. When I try to debug, I can see the JSONArray being created with correct values but then the code abruptly stops at later lines. The code snippet is -

```
private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
                throws JSONException

{

    JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
    Log.v("Jsonobject forcastJson", "done");
    JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);
    Log.v("JsonArray", "done");
    for (int i=0; i< weatherArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject daydata = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.v("daydata", "done");
        JSONObject weatherobject = daydata.getJSONObject(OWM_WEATHER);
        Log.v("weatherobject", "done");
        String description = weatherobject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

        JSONObject tempratureobject = daydata.getJSONObject(OWM_DESCRIPTION);
        Log.v("tempratureobject", "done");
        double high = tempratureobject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
        double low = tempratureobject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);
        highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
```

The JSON is -

```
{
"city":
{
    "id": 5103269,
    "name": "Ridgewood",
    "coord":
    {
        "lon": -74.116531,
        "lat": 40.979259
    },
    "country": "US",
    "population": 0,
    "sys":
    {
        "population": 0
    }
},
"cod": "200",
"message": 0.0292,
"cnt": 7,
"list": [
{
    "dt": 1455742800,
    "main":
    {
        "temp": 2.98,
        "temp_min": 2.98,
        "temp_max": 4.04,
        "pressure": 1025.94,
        "sea_level": 1029.53,
        "grnd_level": 1025.94,
        "humidity": 92,
        "temp_kf": -1.06
    },
    "weather": [
    {
        "id": 801,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "few clouds",
        "icon": "02d"
    }],
    "clouds":
    {
        "all": 24
    },
    "wind":
    {
        "speed": 3.2,
        "deg": 273
    },
    "sys":
    {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2016-02-17 21:00:00"
},
{
    "dt": 1455753600,
    "main":
    {
        "temp": 0.48,
        "temp_min": 0.48,
        "temp_max": 1.28,
        "pressure": 1028.81,
        "sea_level": 1032.42,
        "grnd_level": 1028.81,
        "humidity": 96,
        "temp_kf": -0.79
    },
    "weather": [
    {
        "id": 801,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "few clouds",
        "icon": "02n"
    }],
    "clouds":
    {
        "all": 12
    },
    "wind":
    {
        "speed": 3.76,
        "deg": 276.002
    },
    "sys":
    {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2016-02-18 00:00:00"
},
{
    "dt": 1455764400,
    "main":
    {
        "temp": -0.9,
        "temp_min": -0.9,
        "temp_max": -0.38,
        "pressure": 1031.32,
        "sea_level": 1034.98,
        "grnd_level": 1031.32,
        "humidity": 100,
        "temp_kf": -0.53
    },
    "weather": [
    {
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "sky is clear",
        "icon": "01n"
    }],
    "clouds":
    {
        "all": 0
    },
    "wind":
    {
        "speed": 3.41,
        "deg": 300
    },
    "sys":
    {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2016-02-18 03:00:00"
},
{
    "dt": 1455775200,
    "main":
    {
        "temp": -1.92,
        "temp_min": -1.92,
        "temp_max": -1.67,
        "pressure": 1032.6,
        "sea_level": 1036.23,
        "grnd_level": 1032.6,
        "humidity": 100,
        "temp_kf": -0.26
    },
    "weather": [
    {
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "sky is clear",
        "icon": "01n"
    }],
    "clouds":
    {
        "all": 0
    },
    "wind":
    {
        "speed": 3.61,
        "deg": 289.502
    },
    "sys":
    {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2016-02-18 06:00:00"
},
{
    "dt": 1455786000,
    "main":
    {
        "temp": -2.23,
        "temp_min": -2.23,
        "temp_max": -2.23,
        "pressure": 1035.25,
        "sea_level": 1038.94,
        "grnd_level": 1035.25,
        "humidity": 100,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [
    {
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "sky is clear",
        "icon": "01n"
    }],
    "clouds":
    {
        "all": 0
    },
    "wind":
    {
        "speed": 4.17,
        "deg": 322.001
    },
    "sys":
    {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2016-02-18 09:00:00"
},
{
    "dt": 1455796800,
    "main":
    {
        "temp": -3.76,
        "temp_min": -3.76,
        "temp_max": -3.76,
        "pressure": 1038.33,
        "sea_level": 1042.06,
        "grnd_level": 1038.33,
        "humidity": 100,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [
    {
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "sky is clear",
        "icon": "01d"
    }],
    "clouds":
    {
        "all": 0
    },
    "wind":
    {
        "speed": 3.79,
        "deg": 330.001
    },
    "sys":
    {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2016-02-18 12:00:00"
},
{
    "dt": 1455807600,
    "main":
    {
        "temp": -2.22,
        "temp_min": -2.22,
        "temp_max": -2.22,
        "pressure": 1040.61,
        "sea_level": 1044.24,
        "grnd_level": 1040.61,
        "humidity": 100,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [
    {
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "sky is clear",
        "icon": "01d"
    }],
    "clouds":
    {
        "all": 0
    },
    "wind":
    {
        "speed": 3.78,
        "deg": 341.506
    },
    "sys":
    {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2016-02-18 15:00:00"
}]
}
```

Comment: *code abruptly stops at later lines* means there is something wrong. Please check your logcat once more for stack trace. Also, where does it stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong then value of `OWM_DESCRIPTION` should be `description`

So here is my analysis

1. `JSONObject tempratureobject = daydata.getJSONObject(OWM_DESCRIPTION);`

   should be something like

   ```
   SONObject tempratureobject = daydata.getJSONObject(OWM_MAIN); // use variable which has value "main"
   ```
2. `JSONObject weatherobject = daydata.getJSONObject(OWM_WEATHER);`

   should be

   ```
   JSONObject weatherobject = daydata.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
   ```

   because `weather` node is an Array and you need first object of this array.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. The problem was resolved by first accessing the array for weather node and then the object inside it.

Comment: Perfect. Don't forget to accept the answer then please.

Answer (score 0):

```
String description = weatherobject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

    JSONObject tempratureobject = daydata.getJSONObject(OWM_DESCRIPTION);
```

you refer here to it as a a string and as an objetc, where it is only a string inside your JSON